# Properties set in the constructor of a custom UIButton class are ignored on iOS15

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, ios15

I wanted to check if everything's fine with my app on iOS 15. *Spoiler alert : no*.

I've identified a problem with my buttons, so I've downloaded Visual Studio 2022 Preview, and Xcode-beta which comes with iOS 15.

Here is my custom `UIButton` class (simplified to make it straightforward) :

```
public class AppButton : UIButton
{
    public AppButton(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
        SetTitle("Hello", UIControlState.Normal); // Not working on iOS 15
        Alpha = .2f; // Not working on iOS 15
    }
}
```

In previous iOS versions, it was working fine and each `AppButton` had the title *"Hello"* with a lot of transparency (.2f).

**But in IOS 15, it is not working anymore : `AppButton` have no title, and no transparency.**

It's kind of like nothing in the default constructor is interpreted (I still can debug it with success), or there's something that overrides it after.

Fun fact is I also have an `AppLabel` class that do pretty much the same as this `AppButton` class, and this one works ! So there's obviously a problem with my `AppButton` class... Could [this brand new iOS 15 feature](https://sarunw.com/posts/new-way-to-style-uibutton-in-ios15/) be the troublemaker ?

Comment: What if you use the ctor that takes a Frame? Or are you using this button in a storyboard?

Comment: @Cheesebaron Yeah it's a button in a storyboard.

Comment: I guess the new version of iOS must be using a different ctor. Try override the other ones and see if that helps.

Comment: @Cheesebaron I tried but problem still here.

Comment: What is your Xamarin.ios version?